# path component and orbits

Tags: lie-groups

Consider $G$ lie group and $M$ riemannian manifold, what does it mean to say that that the
points in M/G corresponding to the orbit G(p) and G(q) are in the same path component of
M/G?

Comment: Are you asking for a clarification of path components, or looking for some results that follow from this assumption?

Comment: I am actually trying to understand the final part of the Principal Orbit Theorem, in the part that $M_{pric} / G$ is connected in $M ​​/ G$

Comment: $M_{pric}$ is the set of principal points,